# Requesting suggestions for ubuntu installation

Tags: 22.04, windows

I have a HP laptop with intel and nvidia hardware. I'm thinking to replace Win11 with Ubuntu desktop 22.04. I would like to know if there are any pre-requisite that i should perform on windows before starting the installation and known problems that i'm going face after installation. Below are the few things that i expect to work without any problems.

1. Projector connectivity.
2. Bluetooth, Audio, Video and Camera.

Comment: Also, feel free to first run ubuntu in live mode (a mode that allows you to run ubuntu before installing). If you are happy, install.